# My drop_simulator function for my Plinko lab isn't working

Tags: c++

This is what I've written so far. I thought it would work perfectly, seeing as I mostly transcribed it from my old Plinko lab code where I didn't use functions, changing it so that the simulator chunk became its own function. I get five errors, however.

In line 17 (ran = ran() % 2): "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type". What does this mean?

In line 10 ((srand(time(0));): "'argument': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data". What does this mean?

In line 17 again: "term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments". What does this mean?

In line 99 (drop_simulator(slot_number, 1);): "'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data". How do I prevent this?

In line 129 (total_rewards += drop_simulator(slot_number, 0);): same as above.

I would appreciate any help. I feel I've done everything I possibly can but feel as if I've run into a brick wall with this one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

double drop_simulator(int slot_number, int number_of_chips_dropped)
{
    srand(time(0));
    double plink;
    double ran;
    double location;
    location = slot_number;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {           
        ran = (ran() % 2);
        plink = ran;
        plink -= 0.5;
        location += plink;
        if (location >= 8)
        {
            location -= 1;
        }
        else if (location <= 0)
        {
            location += 1;
        }
        if (number_of_chips_dropped == 1)
        {
            cout << location << endl;
        }
    }
    int reward = 0;
    if (location == 0)
    {
        reward = 100;
    }
    else if (location == 1)
    {
        reward = 500;
    }
    else if (location == 2)
    {
        reward = 1000;
    }
    else if (location == 3)
    {
        reward = 0;
    }
    else if (location == 4)
    {
        reward = 10000;
    }
    else if (location == 5)
    {
        reward = 0;
    }
    else if (location == 6)
    {
        reward = 1000;
    }
    else if (location == 7)
    {
        reward = 500;
    }
    else if (location == 8)
    {
        reward = 100;
    }
    return reward;
}

int main()
{
    int input = 0;
    while (input != 3)
    {
        cout << "Please select one of these three options." << endl;
        cout << "1 - Drop a single chip into one slot" << endl;
        cout << "2 - Drop multiple chips into one slot" << endl;
        cout << "3 - Quit the program" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        cout << endl;

        if (input == 1)
        {
            double slot_number;
            cout << "Pick a slot (0 - 8) into which you'd like to drop your chip: ";
            cin >> slot_number;
            cout << endl;
            if (slot_number < 0 || slot_number > 8)
            {
                cout << "INVALID SELECTION" << endl << endl;
            }
            else if (slot_number >= 0 && slot_number <= 8)
            {
                double reward = 0;
                drop_simulator(slot_number, 1);
                cout << "You won $" << reward << "!" << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (input == 2)
        {
            int number_of_chips_dropped;
            cout << "How many chips would you like to drop?" << endl;
            cin >> number_of_chips_dropped;
            cout << endl;
            if (number_of_chips_dropped <= 0)
            {
                cout << "INVALID SELECTION. Please enter a positive number." << endl << endl;
            }
            else if (number_of_chips_dropped > 0)
            {
                double slot_number;
                cout << "Pick a slot (0 - 8) into which you'd like to drop your chips.";
                cin >> slot_number;
                cout << endl;

                if (slot_number < 0 || slot_number > 8)
                {
                    cout << "INVALID SELECTION" << endl << endl;
                }
                else if (slot_number >= 0 && slot_number <= 8)
                {
                    double total_rewards = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_chips_dropped; i++)
                    {
                        total_rewards += drop_simulator(slot_number, 0);
                    }
                    double average_winnings = total_rewards / number_of_chips_dropped;
                    cout << "The average rewards per chip was $" << average_winnings << "." << endl;
                    cout << "Your total rewards were $" << total_rewards << "." << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (input < 1 || input > 3)
        {
            cout << "INVALID SELECTION. Please enter 1, 2 or 3." << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (input == 3)
        {
            cout << "GOODBYE" << endl << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `ran()` suppose to be `rand()`, and `srand(time(0))` should be `srand(time(NULL))`. Why is `slot_number` a `double` in `main` and an `int` in `drop_simulator`?

Answer (score 1):

The error messages really are trying to tell about the problem:

> Line 17:
>   ran = (ran() % 2);
>
> "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type".

Here `ran()` (the token before the parantheses) is flagged as not being a function or pointer-to-function type.

Similar

> "term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments"

indicates that `ran()`is not known to be a declared function in current scope.

Likely you intended to use `rand()` here to get a random number.

> Line 10:
>   srand(time(0));
>
> argument': "conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data"

`srand`is takig an `unsigned int`as parameter type. You are pasing the return value of `time(0)` to it. This is a `time_t`. (Likely a kind of `long`.) This could loose some bits of precision (`long`to `int`). As you likely would not care for initialyzing the RNG, you could use an explicit cast:

```
srand((unsigned int)time(0));
```

> Line 99:
>   drop_simulator(slot_number, 1);

and

> Line 129:
>   total_rewards += drop_simulator(slot_number, 0);

causing

> "'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data"

suffer from `slot_number` being defined as `double` with `main`while the formal parameter to drop_simulator`is being declared as`ìnt`.  As double can represent more values that int, you get the problem indicated. For fixing this you could just change the declaration of`slot_number`to:

```
int slot_number;
```

in main.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I feel kind of dumb not having noticed how obvious the reasons for the errors were. I'm pretty new to programming and this is the first class I've ever taken for it, and so far I'm loving it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> In line 17 (ran = ran() % 2): "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type". What does this mean?

This is because `ran` is not a function name, you perhaps intended

```
ran = rand() % 2
```

which makes ran be the result of a call to function `rand` modulo'd by 2.

This will fix your second error on line 17.

> In line 99 (drop_simulator(slot_number, 1);): "'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data". How do I prevent this?
>
> In line 129 (total_rewards += drop_simulator(slot_number, 0);): same as above.

This is because you've needlessly declared "slot_number" as a double. This means a user could enter a value such as "1.2345" which you don't want. Simply change your declarations of `slot_number` from `double slot_number` to `int slot_number`.

> In line 10 ((srand(time(0));): "'argument': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data". What does this mean?

It means that `srand` expects an unsigned integer but `time(0)` returns a `time_t`. You can fix this with casting:

```
srand(unsigned int(time(0)));
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

double drop_simulator(int slot_number, int number_of_chips_dropped)
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    double plink;
    double ran;
    double location;
    location = slot_number;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        ran = (rand() % 2);
        plink = ran;
        plink -= 0.5;
        location += plink;
        if (location >= 8)
        {
            location -= 1;
        }
        else if (location <= 0)
        {
            location += 1;
        }
        if (number_of_chips_dropped == 1)
        {
            cout << location << endl;
        }
    }
    int reward = 0;
    if (location == 0)
    {
        reward = 100;
    }
    else if (location == 1)
    {
        reward = 500;
    }
    else if (location == 2)
    {
        reward = 1000;
    }
    else if (location == 3)
    {
        reward = 0;
    }
    else if (location == 4)
    {
        reward = 10000;
    }
    else if (location == 5)
    {
        reward = 0;
    }
    else if (location == 6)
    {
        reward = 1000;
    }
    else if (location == 7)
    {
        reward = 500;
    }
    else if (location == 8)
    {
        reward = 100;
    }
    return reward;
}

int main()
{
    int input = 0;
    while (input != 3)
    {
        cout << "Please select one of these three options." << endl;
        cout << "1 - Drop a single chip into one slot" << endl;
        cout << "2 - Drop multiple chips into one slot" << endl;
        cout << "3 - Quit the program" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        cout << endl;

        if (input == 1)
        {
            int slot_number;
            cout << "Pick a slot (0 - 8) into which you'd like to drop your chip: ";
            cin >> slot_number;
            cout << endl;
            if (slot_number < 0 || slot_number > 8)
            {
                cout << "INVALID SELECTION" << endl << endl;
            }
            else if (slot_number >= 0 && slot_number <= 8)
            {
                double reward = 0;
                drop_simulator(slot_number, 1);
                cout << "You won $" << reward << "!" << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (input == 2)
        {
            int number_of_chips_dropped;
            cout << "How many chips would you like to drop?" << endl;
            cin >> number_of_chips_dropped;
            cout << endl;
            if (number_of_chips_dropped <= 0)
            {
                cout << "INVALID SELECTION. Please enter a positive number." << endl << endl;
            }
            else if (number_of_chips_dropped > 0)
            {
                int slot_number;
                cout << "Pick a slot (0 - 8) into which you'd like to drop your chips.";
                cin >> slot_number;
                cout << endl;

                if (slot_number < 0 || slot_number > 8)
                {
                    cout << "INVALID SELECTION" << endl << endl;
                }
                else if (slot_number >= 0 && slot_number <= 8)
                {
                    double total_rewards = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_chips_dropped; i++)
                    {
                        total_rewards += drop_simulator(slot_number, 0);
                    }
                    double average_winnings = total_rewards / number_of_chips_dropped;
                    cout << "The average rewards per chip was $" << average_winnings << "." << endl;
                    cout << "Your total rewards were $" << total_rewards << "." << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (input < 1 || input > 3)
        {
            cout << "INVALID SELECTION. Please enter 1, 2 or 3." << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (input == 3)
        {
            cout << "GOODBYE" << endl << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

live demo: http://ideone.com/dp7sLN

Comment: I hadn't realized that I'd declared slot_number to be a double in some locations and an int in others. Thanks for helping me out.